# Silverlight 4: Draw Vertical / Horizontal Rulers to Scale

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight-4.0, wpf-controls, silverlightcontrols

I am looking for options on how to draw 2 rulers at different scales on a canvas (assume a canvas) that will scale based on user-entered data.

Placing the tick marks and text one-time isn't a big deal, it is how to scale the data as the max/min values are changed by the user AND getting the points (ellipses) on the canvas to look correctly.

Foolishly, I set the size of the canvas to the max values of the current data, but as the data changes that won't work... I had hoped for a 1:1 translation...

Something like taking the current canvas size and redrawing the rulers is where I am headed

thanks,

rusty

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was over thinking the issue plus have just started in 'drawing', 'graphics', etc.  Have a lot to learn.  It was basic logical to physical translation math that most everyone 'knows'.

rusty